# elm - union types and the model

Tags: view, model, action, elm

The following code from [this](http://elm-lang.org/guide/model-the-problem) guide employs a union type to hold all possible widget types, then render a view:

```elm
type Widget
    = ScatterPlot (List (Int, Int))
    | LogData (List String)
    | TimePlot (List (Time, Int))

view : Widget -> Element
view widget =
    case widget of
      ScatterPlot points ->
          viewScatterPlot points

      LogData logs ->
          flow down (map viewLog logs)

      TimePlot occurrences ->
          viewTimePlot occurrences
```

My rather elementary question is:

With respect to the `Widget` type, what is the underlying model here?

Given an action (e.g. user wants to see a scatter graph widget), what is the underlying structure that should be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Widget is your raw data. You then need to model separately which data to show

```elm
type alias Model = Widget
```

Then suppose that you have some incoming IO data

```elm
update action model = 
  case action of 
    ScatterPoints pts ->     -- List (Int, Int)
      ScatterPlot pts
    LogPoints pts ->
      LogData pts
    ...
```

then having loaded the data in the right type of Widget your view function from the original question will know what to do with the data

Comment: Are permutations of 2 or 3 widget types outside the scope of the example? I was wondering what would need to be updated if the user wanted to switch from one widget type to another.

Comment: You would need a user event to trigger the update cycle, and a function that transforms the data to the new format